# Python Script to Perform an Event While RFID Tag is In Contact with RFID Reader

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, rfid

I am attempting to write a python script on my Raspberry Pi 4 that turns an LED on with an RFID tag and this LED remains on while the RFID tag is in proximity of the reader. When I hold the card to the reader the LED blinks instead of remaining on constantly. I also have an issue where when I remove the tag from the reader on a "Card Found" step, the loop stops iterating and the "No Card in Range" text stops being outputted.

Please see my code below:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

blueled = LED(4)

while True:
    status,TagType = reader.read_no_block()
    
    if (status == None):
        print("No Card in Range")
        blueled.off()
    elif (status != None):
        print("Card Found")
        id, text = reader.read()

        if (id == 965463577380):
            blueled.on()
```

Here is what my code outputs while running:

```
No Card in Range
No Card in Range
No Card in Range
No Card in Range
Card Found
No Card in Range
Card Found
No Card in Range
Card Found
```